# How can I set up a table in Microsoft Word such that the table extends to the maximum printed edges of the page?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, printing

Further from the title of the question:

How can I ensure that the edges of the table reaches the edges of the maximum printed areas of the page, to maximize the table to the point it fits the entire page when printed on A4?

I try to explain my problem with the following images:

[Top part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMUAQ.png)

[Bottom part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeHFD.png)

Is there a setting to do so? I tried so hard moving the table up and its so difficult because it doesn't seem to react to my input.

Please suggest a "make sure" way of setting the table to the maximum possible printable area on the Word document, if possible.

I am using Microsoft Word 365.

Comment: Remove any headers or footers?

Comment: @DavidPostill I can try this, how do I remove them?

Comment: Not sure - Format Page or Format Section?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways.

One way is to set all your Page Margins to 0 (if your printer cannot print all the way to the edge you will get a warning that it is outside the printable area), set the Table width to 100% or however many inches wide the page is, then set the row height to the height of the page (I like to set "Row height is" to "Exactly" instead of "At least" and also un-check "Allow row to break across pages" they're not necessary but may help). Now you should have a single cell table that fully covers the page. If you need multiple columns or rows you'll need to either split the table and figure out the measurements for each column and row to maintain full coverage or create a nested table.

Another way is to change the Table's Text Wrapping option to "Around" which (if you know HTML) is very similar to floating the table so you can "break out" of containers. Then click the "Positioning..." button and set them as shown in my attached image. The important settings on the Table Positioning are the "Realitive to" options, you want those set to "Page" and the distance all set to 0. Then same as the first method, set the Table width to the width of the page and the row height to the height of the page.

Note: It can be a little cumbersome getting the heights and widths just right especially when you start adding content and breaking up cells, but you can get it there adjusting the heights of the rows and widths of the table/columns. If you are planning to have this table as the only thing in your document, Word, for whatever reason, forces a new line at the end of the document. You may get stuck with a blank page at the end. I can sometimes get around that by setting the new line's paragraph settings to have no spacing and the smallest font possible and make my table height just a little less to allow the newline room on the first page.

[image: Full size table in Word]

Answer (score 0):

*Following up on comment from @DavidPostill.*

I am assuming without evidence that you are using Word for Windows, not on a Mac. The structural changes are the same on a Mac but the controls are a bit different. You are dealing with [Section Properties](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/formatting/workwithsections.htm) and with [Headers and Footers](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings) which are a part of Section Properties.

- [Working With Sections](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/formatting/workwithsections.htm) by Dave Rado, MVP
- [Header and Footer Settings Recap](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/formatting/workwithsections.htm) on my web site.

### In the Middle of a Document With Other Text

If your table is in other text and you want to have normal margins for that other text, you will need to set your document up to have page SECTION breaks around it. This is done under the Layout Tab. Before your table: Breaks > Next Page and after Breaks > Next Page.

Then in the Headers and Footers Tab make sure your headers and footers are not "Linked to Previous." Do this for both the header and footer. This should be done in the section that contains your table and the following section. Then make the changes to the headers and footers in the section that contains your table without changing others.

### Header and Footer Size - Do this after adding section breaks!

While you cannot remove headers and footers in Word *(they are a part of the document structure)*, you can shrink them. This can be done in the Header/Footer Tab or in the Page Layout dialog. You can change the distance reserved to .1.

[image: Controls on Header/Footer Tab]

Note that each header and footer has an *empty paragraph* in it. You can see these by displaying non-printing formatting marks. While you cannot delete those empty paragraphs, you can also shrink them. Go into each header and footer. Use Ctrl+A to select all text and then change the font size to 1 point. (You have to type the 1.)

Your header and footer may also have paragraph spacing set for space before or space after. This is paragraph formatting and can be changed in the Format Paragraph dialog that you can reach by clicking on the Dialog Launcher (little arrow in the bottom right of the Paragraph Group).

### Final Caveats

- Any change in the Printer Driver being used changes the printable area. This may be different on different computers even if they are using the same printer.
- Page numbering gets trickier with multiple sections. See my writing on [Page Numbering in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers).